# Integrating MSM with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've used MSM to build a multi state model and would like to integrate the features of ggplot2 to look at predictive survival from the various states.  However, I would like to use ggplot2 to produce the graphics but these curves are created from the MSM function.  Is there a way that the two can work together?  At the moment I use the plot.survfit.msm to create them but would like something more flexible.
Thanks.

Comment: If msm behaves like `lm`/`nlm`/etc., you might be able to use it directly with ggplot2's `stat_smooth`. Otherwise, the fallback is to just manually make a data frame with all of your predictions, and then use that.

Comment: If you post a small reproducible example, we can give more specific advice.